# Confused about how to play sound

Tags: java

What I want to do is very clear, just play a sound and pause it. The problem is that I can't pause the music. I can't find a mistake; what am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainC extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    int Copened,Cplay,Cstop,Csave,Cpause;
    AudioStream aStream;
    String Filename;
    File file;

    FileInputStream fis;
    public MainC() {
        Filename="";
        txtname=new JTextField();
        chooser=new JFileChooser();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btnopen){
            chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            file=chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }

        if(e.getSource()==btnPause){
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(fis);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==btnplay){
                fis=new  FileInputStream(file);
                aStream=new AudioStream(fis);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(aStream);
```

Comment: for starters, you are missing quite a few closing braces

Comment: You use the `fis` variable before it is declared, and inside the scope of another `if` statement. You could try making `fis` a class variable, that could solve it.

Comment: Don't use classes from 'sun.audio' they are not part of the Java public API. Look at the [javasound tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for lots of info on Java sound

Comment: Using sound in Java with just what the JDK gives you is pretty difficult for a beginner, it may be easier to use a library like [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound/blob/master/example/TinySoundExample.java).

Comment: You should use lowercase for variable names. Also, consider using an `Enum` rather than `int` for `cOpened`, `cPlay`, etc... See this link for the Java coding standards. Scroll down to section 5.0 for naming standards. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarations

Comment: You need to show more code. A fuller account will help.

Comment: @MightPork No, he just didn't copy it all.

Comment: @ DaaaahWhoosh  Please Show me what you mean on the source code